# Single Click issue in IE 6

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have the following code. The code populates a list box basing on the selection done. But my code works on IE 7 & fails on IE 6.

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//fill the location list on the basis of Country

function FillLocationList()
{
    var opt =  document.createElement("OPTION");
    var selected =document.getElementById('drpCountryName').selectedIndex;
    var size = document.getElementById('drpCountryName').options.length;
     if(!event.ctrlKey && !event.shiftKey)
     {

        document.getElementById('drpLocation').options.length = 0;
        for(var i=0;i<locationArray.value.length;i++)
        {

            //if(document.getElementById('drpLocationReportsTo').value == locationArray.value[i].LocationRptId)
            if(document.getElementById('drpCountryName').value == locationArray.value[i].CountryCode)
            {
                 opt =  document.createElement("OPTION");
                 opt.text = locationArray.value[i].LocationName;
                 opt.value=locationArray.value[i].LocationId;
                 document.getElementById("drpLocation").options.add(opt);
            }
        }

     }


    else if(event.ctrlKey || event.shiftKey)
    {

        document.getElementById('drpLocation').length = 0;
        for(j=0;j<document.getElementById('drpCountryName').length;j++)
        {
           var currentLocation = document.getElementById('drpCountryName').options[j].value;
            if(document.getElementById('drpCountryName').options[j].selected)
            {   
                for(var i=0;i<locationArray.value.length;i++)
                {

                    if(currentLocation == locationArray.value[i].CountryCode)
                    {
                         opt =  document.createElement("OPTION");
                         opt.text = locationArray.value[i].LocationName;
                         opt.value=locationArray.value[i].LocationId;
                         document.getElementById("drpLocation").options.add(opt);
                    }
                }
            }
       }

    }

}
```

Comment: Works for me in IE6, full test case please. However note that `options.add` is a non-standard method that won't work outside IE (use eg. `options[options.length]= opt` instead) and the use of global `event` is IE-only (and probably inadvisable in any case).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the function fired under IE6? Because a common problem is to attach the function to the `onclick` event (which has problems under IE6).

Use `onchange` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are firing it from the onclick in IE6 try this, well if you are not already doing it this way. IE6 has some issues with firing javascript functions in the onclick event.

onclick="FillLocationList(); event.returnValue=false; return false;"

Comment: It seems to be a intermittent problem as well, in some pages I have just done return false; and it works fine. In other situations it just doesn't work so I have to use this work around. Don't you love IE6.

Comment: I've found that some delay or different internal execution path causes this intermittent problems.

Comment: Interesting, I will pay attention to the execution path next time I run into the issue. Thanks.